# Do prepare for the presentation. Is this a correct phrase?

Tags: word-usage

Any suggestions? The actual message is "Please have a look on the presentation that I have uploaded on Dropbox. Please do prepare for the presentation".

Comment: Edit: Is "Please do prepare for the presentation" grammatically right?

It sounds fine to me seriously but grammatically, I don't know.

Comment: Sounds fine, but personally I would emphasise "do": Please *do* prepare for the presentation. I think it’s a colloquialism and the emphasis shows this more clearly.

Comment: Can't you just say ΅Please prepare for the presentation"? Not a hundred percent sure, so I added a comment instead of an answer...

Comment: Adding 'do' before the imperative statement is fine, as is adding the initial 'please'. There's a hint of a patronising formality.

Comment: @Andrew Leach That doesn't expressly cover do-support (or is it?) with imperatives.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth But it does — well, do-support for emphasis: did you read the top answer? However, if you feel there's a better duplicate (there are surely others), please suggest it.

Comment: The reason I haven't close-voted is that I can't find a true duplicate. But the reasons I've not given an 'answer' are: (a) like you, I feel there must be a duplicate, and (b) the overlap is considerable. // I'd say 'Do go ...' is more of a hedge than an emphasiser usage; 'Go ...' is more hortative.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I think you need a better duplicate. The one you choose does not make sense. This is not comparing those two words, and it hard for some people to relate the link you posted to the words they are using. If you must close that question, at least have a solid reason.